# Entity Framework with multiple creation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm curious to know how this works.
If my class A create a data context with

```
dbContext = new S_ERP_DBEntities();
```

Then later, my class A calls a method in class B that also needs a data context so I again do

```
dbContext = new S_ERP_DBEntities();
```

Does it open multiples connections to the DB or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Using `new` anywhere will create new instances each time its used.

There are quite many different theories and situations where you might need to have multiple connections to database or you might want to play with a `singleton` object i.e only one instance throughout the application. It all comes down to application specific requirements and the kind of object handling you want to implement.

Hope this clears the basic idea.

Comment: What about a huge application like an ERP system? should one use single instance or a new instance in each class?

Comment: It depends. If your object is heavy to initialize then a single instance could prove better. If your application is put up online and you are making use of Sessions or some kind of user session handling, then its less risky to create multiple instances for every user. You'll have to read out some articles to find what suits you best for your requirement.

Comment: For the database connection instances, quite many people prefer using the same context object instead of recreating it since it comes in use many times and its costly to recreate everytime.

Comment: THANKS for your comments. I will look into it

Comment: DbContext's cost nothing to create, they in themselves don't open connections to a database, which is the most expensive part of a DbContext (time/performance wise).  DbContext can be quite expensive and become memory hogs because by default they keep all objects you request in memory (unless otherwise configured).

Comment: @AwaisMahmood You should not ask questions as comments, instead you should head over to Programming.stackexchange.com and ask that question.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it open multiples connections to the DB or only one?

Depends on how you use it and it depends on your definition of *open multiple connections*.  This is not a straight forward and easy question.

One of the only ways you will *open multiple connections simultaneously* (most common in new code) is if you uses some async commands like:

```
using (var dbContext1 = new S_ERP_DBEntities())
using (var dbContext2 = new S_ERP_DBEntities())
{
    var cars = await dbcontext1.Cars.ToListAsync();
    var cars = await dbcontext2.Cars.ToListAsync(); 
}
```

In this example, there is only a good chance that two connections will open and then both will close.  Otherwise, most code runs synchronously and therefore each request for EF to execute sql will open and close before then next line of code executes.

It's more complicated because the application pool has one or more [connection pools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).  If the connection strings are the same then the same *connection* can be used my multiple contexts (even on different requests or different contexts).